# Make React PWA project offline (react-scripts 3.4.3)

Tags: reactjs, fetch, progressive-web-apps, offline, react-scripts

I am trying to make a PWA React project offline (Without ejecting) and all the documents are related to the `CRA/react-scripts 4.*`. My project is created with the older version of CRA and uses `react-scripts 3.4.3`.

My understanding of the changes I need to apply is that I need to [handle the `fetch` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Offline_Service_workers#responding_to_fetches). I have tried to change my `serviceWorker.ts` in a way that it generates correct output but I was so off the track.

I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to customize the service worker without adding new packages to the project?
2. Is it better to migrate to the new version? (personally like to use the newest version, but I am not knowledgeable enough to do the migration without loads of trial and error.)
3. If the answer to the first question is `no`, what other option do I have?
4. I have seen in several places that there is not a tool to update `react-scripts` (I mean `CRA` template), is it still the case? The questions are a few months old.

#### serviceWorker.ts:

```js
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

import { pwaHelper } from "utilities";

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.

// To learn more about the benefits of this model and instructions on how to
// opt-in, read ....
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === "localhost" ||
  // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
  window.location.hostname === "[::1]" ||
  // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
  window.location.hostname.match(
    /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/,
  ),
);

// tslint:disable: no-console

interface IConfig {
  onSuccess?: (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => void;
  onUpdate?: (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => void;
}

export function register(config?: IConfig) {

  window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (e: any) => {
    // Prevent the mini-infobar from appearing on mobile
    e.preventDefault();
    // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
    pwaHelper.setEvent(e);
  });

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" && "serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(
      (process as { env: { [key: string]: string } }).env.PUBLIC_URL,
      window.location.href,
    );
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            "This web app is being served cache-first by a service " +
            "worker. To learn more, visit ....",
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl: string, config?: IConfig) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then((registration) => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === "installed") {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              pwaHelper.updateFound(registration);

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log("Content is cached for offline use.");

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error during service worker registration:", error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl: string, config?: IConfig) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then((response) => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf("javascript") === -1)
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        "No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.",
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

#### package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.8.0",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.6",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "jalaali-js": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "marked": "^1.2.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-easy-crop": "^3.3.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.7.0",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "react-modern-calendar-datepicker": "^3.1.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:stage": "env-cmd -f .env.stage react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/helper-call-delegate": "^7.12.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.0.4",
    "@types/google-map-react": "^1.1.5",
    "@types/invariant": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/jalaali-js": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/marked": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.6",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.9",
    "@types/react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.7",
    "@types/yup": "^0.26.31",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.12.0"
  }
}
```

### Update

I have migrated to (react-scripts `4.0.1`) and the fetch issue is fixed. My app works fine offline but the `beforeinstallpromptis` never get fired in Chrome (previously was working on both Chrome and Edge but now only works on Edge.).

[image]

Comment: I actually did this yesterday and I just started a new little project using this CRA template:  `npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa-typescript` (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/). I then just compared what the new stuff looked like (there are 3 new files and several workbox packages that need to be installed) and copied that over into my existing app, updated package.json to use react-scripts 4.0.1, and everything worked.

Comment: @ellitt thank you for your reply. I can see only `serviceWorkerRegistration.ts` and `service-worker.ts` related to this issue.`reportWebVitals.ts` seems to be something else. Also, do I need to add the workbox package to dependencies to dev dependencies will do the trick?

Comment: Also, after applying all have you mentioned, I am facing with `Can't resolve '../fonts/Sahel.eot' in '..\WebClient\src\style'` in build time. I use `scss` for styling.

Comment: Might rollback for now as [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9870) suggests the font issue will be sorted in the next patch.

Comment: The workbox packages should be left as normal dependencies in package.json. As I understand it, CRA prevents some or all of the normal PWA functionality when it's running on localhost, so those workbox packages don't need to be in dev as far as I know. Can't speak to that font loading problem, but hopefully they patch it like you mentioned!